# Parse RSS and if date matches current date then proceed to download

Tags: powershell

Idea is to check RSS feed for `<updated> </updated>` if the RSS Updated header is updated matching the date that it is currently being run to then proceed to download.

Sample RSS Feed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text"> Updates</title>
    <subtitle type="html"><![CDATA[Latest  updates]]></subtitle>
    <link href="http://website/website.rss"></link>
    <id>http://website</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://website/website.rss" ></link>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://website/site/download" ></link>
    <logo>http://website/website</logo>
        <updated>2020-03-28 T17:32:48+00:00</updated>
        <entry>
            <author>
                <name>ueam</name>
            </author>
            <title type="text"><![CDATA[2.0.4516]]></title>
            <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://website/site/download"></link>
            <id>https://website/site/download</id>
            <summary type="html"><![CDATA[<ul>
<li>Patched for March 23rd update</li>
<li>Fixed known bug JIRA</li>
</ul>]]></summary>
            <content type="html"><![CDATA[]]></content>
            <updated>2020-03-28 17:32:48</updated>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <author>
                <name>Team</name>
            </author>
            <title type="text"><![CDATA[2.0.4516]]></title>
            <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://website/site/download"></link>
            <id>https://website/site/download</id>
            <summary type="html"><![CDATA[<ul>
        <li>
        Patch for March 23rd update 
    </li>
    </ul>]]></summary>
            <content type="html"><![CDATA[]]></content>
            <updated>2020-03-28 17:32:48</updated>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <author>
                <name>Team</name>
            </author>
            <title type="text"><![CDATA[2.0.4514]]></title>
            <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://website/site/download></link>
            <id>https://website/site/download</id>
            <summary type="html"><![CDATA[<ul>
<li>Fixed Bug</li>
```

Here

```
<updated>2020-03-28 17:32:48</updated>
```

is shown which if I was running today then would proceed to download since it matches the current day

The download would then called via

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://website/site/download
```

I am just not sure how to parse the RSS to look at the "updated" and compare against current date and if date matches then proceed to download.

**Update:
I tried the below**

```
   #Grab RSS
$rssString = Invoke-WebRequest "http://website/website.rss"

# convert rss to xml
$xml = [xml] $rssString

# select the <updated> node
$updateString = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/feed/updated").innerText

# convert string to date
$date = Get-Date $updateString

# compare to todays date
if($date.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){
  # proceed to download
}
```

You get this error:
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."

When you run

> $updatestring

nothing is returned and is blank, seems that the updated node is not being read

Answer (score 0):

RSS is xml, so treat it as such :)

The `<updated>` node immediately under the root `<feed>` seems to reflect the latest update, so grab that:

```
# convert rss to xml
$xml = [xml]$rssString; 

# select the <updated> node
$updateString = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/feed/updated").innerText

# convert string to date
$date = Get-Date $updateString

# compare to todays date
if($date.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){
  # proceed to download
}
```

Comment: I get error 
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."